# How to create File object in Java without saving to hard disk

Tags: java, file, io

Can you create a File object in Java without saving to hard disk?

All the constructors for java.io.File seem to take info about a location on disk.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? Do you actually want a stream?

Comment: Yeah I guess I just need a stream. But my main goal is persist the file object in a DB4O database as well as on disk, as a .groovy file.

Comment: So... You *do* want to save it to the disk. Why can't you just create a string and write it to the dB and the file? I'm confused regarding the actual issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `File` object is not a file. It is a path to a location on disk with some utility methods. This location *need not exist* to have a valid file. For instance, you can do `File#createNewFile` to create a physical file after creating a `File` object that would point to that pathname on disk.

Use `URL` and related classes to read remotely, or some sort of `java.nio.ByteBuffer` to store file data in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you create a file object, the file itself does not need to exist on disk.

When constructing the java object, you need to specify a location of the file absolute or relative to the current directory, but the file itself does not need to exist on disk.